# Provide Example of Apify Actor Handling State Persistence

Tags: apify

The Apify documentation recommends handling

[State persistence:](https://docs.apify.com/actor/run#state-persistence)
Unlike traditional serverless platforms, actors have no limits on the duration of an actor run. However, that means that an actor might need to be restarted from time to time, e.g. when the server it's running on is to be shutdown. Actors need to account for this possibility. For short-running actors, the chance of a restart is quite low and the cost of repeated runs is low, so restarts can be ignored. However, for long-running actors a restart might be very costly and therefore such *actors should periodically persist their state, possibly to the key-value store associated with the actor run. On start, actors should first check whether there is some state stored and if so they should continue where they left off*.

Please provide an example of an actor:

- periodically persist their state, possibly to the key-value store associated
- on start, actors should first check whether there is some state stored
- continue where they left off

Answer (score 0):

Current state is persisted automatically by the elementary tools like `requestQueue` and `requestList` and for the latter you can also trigger it manually at a higher frequency as detailed here: https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/request-list#requestlistpersiststate

If you don't use the crawler classes and need to persist some custom state data during the actor's runtime, it's recommended to use the key-value store where you can save arbitrary data with proper content type as explained here: https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/key-value-store#keyvaluestoresetvaluekey-value-options

For restoring previous state, you can load the state data saved previously again from the store into the variables you need to hold the state, to restore previous state in memory. If you don't specify content type, it's JSON by default and when you load it from key-value store you can use it directly as an object holding your state information without having to do additional parsing.